# Identify part of the lyrics from the play Roméo et Juliette, song "Sans elle"

Tags: paroles-de-chanson

I was watching the 2001 musical play *Roméo et Juliette, de la Haine à l'Amour* and was a bit lost about one line in a late-play song *Sans elle*.

The part of the lyrics I could figure out by searching online and listen to repeatedly is as follows:

> N'a pas besoin (*Nous pardonnons vos offenses, ooh*)
>
> Chez elle, tout est jardin (*Tout ça n'a pas d'importance*)
>
> Le bleu de son ciel (`???` *serons ensemble*)
>
> C'n'est pas du rimmel (*Quand je pense à lui, je tremble*)

I have listened to this part  more than two hundred times but still couldn't figure out the words;  see that part marked with question marks in the above snippet. The closest I got was *bien que de*, which looks very wrong even if in the context of a song where grammar rules are generally less strictly enforced.

Other variants that I've seen online, which would make even less sense:

- *Bientôt nous serons ensemble* (*bientôt* is not understood here)
- *Et demain, nous seront seuls* (the first few syllables contain no /m/ sound)
- *Le bleu de mon ciel* (the last word sounds nowhere like *ciel*)

I'm really curious about what the "correct" or "intended" words are. Should you need to listen, this song is [available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wg_-uhTjUw&t=2m45s) (starting from 2m45s).

Comment: Are you sure this is Sans Elle? Here are some words I found: https://paroles2chansons.lemonde.fr/paroles-romeo-juliet/paroles-sans-elle.html

Comment: @Lambie It is definitely *Sans Elle*. What makes you think it is not?

Comment: @Lambie The one you linked provides *et demain* for the questioned line. I couldn't hear anything like *demain*.

Comment: @jlliagre Sorry I didn't know that. I've changed it back. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Why do you think that bientôt nous serons ensemble wouldn't make much sense?

Comment: @jlliagre Given the context of the play, *serons ensemble* isn't true, but *serons seuls* may be more suitable.

Comment: @iBug I definitely hear "bientôt nous serons ensembles". If this song is about Romeo and Juliet, I see two easy ways this could make sense. 1. They will be together in death (said after seeing Romeo's death), or 2. She is simply expressing her belief about any event happening at that time: "It doesn't matter, we'll be together soon". Whether this ends up true or not doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Simon That looks like a complete (and better) answer to me. Would you mind posting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely hear without a doubt ***Bientôt** nous seron[s] ensemble*. The sentence she said right before is *Ça n'a pas d'importance*. The full message is "It has no importance/it doesn't matter, we will be together soon". I didn't analyze the lyrics, but if this song is about Romeo and Juliet, I see a couple of ways this can make sense:

- She might have said that after realizing the tragic death of Romeo. The meaning would be that it doesn't matter because they would be together in death or even together after dying.
- As a more general approach, she might simply be commenting on a certain situation and expressing her feelings and belief at that point in time. No matter what happens, it doesn't matter because we'll be together soon.

After reading more of the lyrics, the second interpretation seems to be correct, because she keeps repeating *Ça n'a pas d'importance*, and the first comment she makes is *Nous pardonnons vos offenses* (I forgive your "offenses"?). If I remember correctly, Romeo killed someone and got in trouble for it. So the general idea here would be that it doesn't matter at all for her, she's just thinking about being with him, even if it ends up not happening.

Comment: Interesting to know, but isn't "offense" a word? (There is *offenser, j'offense*.)

Comment: Though I'm still having trouble identifying the first word as *bientôt*, this is the most comprehensive explanation so far, so +1 and accept.

Comment: @iBug Yes offense is a word, but I was unsure if the nuance was the same in English for this context, that's why I added the questioning. It's definitely hard to hear it because it's muffled and the man is speaking louder over her.

Answer (score 0):

I believe she says either ***Bien sûr** nous serons ensemble* or ***Bientôt** nous serons ensemble*.

The latter seems to be the right one according to a quick internet search:

- [Source 1](https://www.letras.com/romeo-e-juliette/57245/) - letras.com
- [Source 2](https://www.stlyrics.com/songs/r/romoetjuliette8389/sanselleenlive968139.html)  - stlyrics.com

Comment: I'm not convinced that the leading consonant of the second syllable is /s/. It sounds more like /k/ to me.

Comment: The soundtrack is not crystal clear (to say the least) but I really don't hear a /k/.  My second guess would be *bientôt nous serons ensemble*.

Comment: J'entends _bientôt_ et pas de liaison entre _serons_ et _ensemble_.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Ce n'est pas necessaire qu'il y a de liaison entre *serons* et *ensemble*.

Comment: C'est vrai, la phrase reste valide mais c'est un point quand même notable car les liaisons optionnelles sont plus souvent réalisées en poésie ou dans les chansons que dans l'expression orale habituelle.